# Tab control is not working in jquery mobile?

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

I have created one jquery mobile site which having the tab control and it is not working when we are seeing the page at the first time,but after reloading the page it is working.

I wanted to make it should work before reloading also.....

Here the code For that ....

```
<?php
require_once"session.php";
require_once"getDetails.php";
$docId =$_GET['docId'];
$selDoc=$dbHandle->execQuery("SELECT * FROM master_doctor WHERE doctor_id='$docId'");
$fetDoc=$dbHandle->fetchObjectQuery($selDoc);

$qlfyVal='';
$qualId =explode(",",$fetDoc->qualification_id);
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($qualId);$i++)
{
    $qlfyVal .=comnName('doc_qualification','name','qualification_id',$qualId[$i]).',';
}
$qlfyVal =substr($qlfyVal,0,strlen($qlfyVal)-1);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title><?php echo $fetDoc->salutation.'.'.ucfirst($fetDoc->fname).ucfirst($fetDoc->lname).' '.$qlfyVal;?> Details</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <?php require_once"header.php";?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowHide(id)
        {
            $('.datatab').each(function(){
                if($(this).attr('id') != id)
                {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
                else
                {
                    $(this).show();
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head> 
<body> 
<div data-role="page" id="docView" >
    <div data-role=header data-theme="e" >
        <a href="doctorgrid.php" data-icon="back" ><font size="2px">back</font></a>
        <h1 align="left"><font size="2px"><?php echo $fetDoc->salutation.'.'.ucfirst($fetDoc->fname).ucfirst($fetDoc->lname).' '.$qlfyVal;?> Details</font></h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role=content>
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li class="tabLi"><a onclick="ShowHide('contact')" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="tabLi"><a  onclick="ShowHide('primary')">Primary</a></li>
            <li class="tabLi"><a  onclick="ShowHide('working')">Working</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="data-clear">
    </div>
    <div id="contact" class="datatab" >
    <ul data-role=listview data-inset=true data-theme=d>
      <li data-theme=e  ><font size="2px"> Contact Info </font></li>

      <li><font size="2px"> Phone No : 
      <?php 
      function ckVal($val,$ref)
      {
        $tmp="NA";
        if($val != '')
        {
            if($ref == 'tel')
            {
                $tmp =',<a href="tel:'.$val.'">'.$val.'</a>';
            }
            else if($ref == 'mail')
            {
                $tmp =',<a href="mail:'.$val.'">'.$val.'</a>';
            }
            else
            {
                $tmp =','.$val;
            }
        }
        return $tmp;
      }
     if($fetDoc->phone1!= '')
     {
        $ctNo ='<br/><a href="tel:'.$fetDoc->phone1.'">'.$fetDoc->phone1.'</a><br/>'.ckVal($fetDoc->phone2,'tel').'<br/>'.ckVal($fetDoc->mobile1,'tel').'<br/>'.ckVal($fetDoc->mobile2,'tel');
     }
     else
     {
        $ctNo ='<br/>'.ckVal($fetDoc->phone2,'tel').ckVal($fetDoc->mobile1,'tel').ckVal($fetDoc->mobile2,'tel');
     }
     echo $ctNo;
     ?></font></li>

      <li><font size="2px"> Mail : <?php 
      if($fetDoc->official_email != '')
      {
        $ctMail ='<br/><a href="mail:'.$fetDoc->official_email.'">'.$fetDoc->official_email.'</a><br/>'.ckVal($fetDoc->personal_email,'mail');
      }
      else
      {
        $ctMail ='<br/>'.ckVal($fetDoc->personal_email,'mail');
      }

      echo $ctMail;?> </font></li>

      <li><font size="2px"> Address : <?php 
      if($fetDoc->address1 != '')
      {
        $ctAddr ='<br/>'.$fetDoc->address1.'<br/>'.ckVal($fetDoc->address2,'');
      }
      else
      {
        $ctAddr ='<br/>'.ckVal($fetDoc->address2,'');
      }

      echo $ctAddr;?> </font></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="primary" class="datatab" style="display:none">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="d" >

    <li data-theme=e  ><font size="2px"> Primary Info </font></li>

      <li><font size="2px"> Specialization : 
      <?php
        $splfyVal='';
        $splfyId =explode(",",$fetDoc->specialization_id);
        for($i=0;$i<sizeof($splfyId);$i++)
        {
            $splfyVal .=comnName('doc_specialization','name','specialization_id',$splfyId[$i]).',';
        }
        $splfyVal =substr($splfyVal,0,strlen($splfyVal)-1);
        echo $splfyVal;
      ?>
      </font></li>

      <li><font size="2px"> Patients / day : <?php echo $fetDoc->ave_patients;?> </font></li>

      <li><font size="2px"> Total RX Potental : 
        <?php
        $slRx =$dbHandle->execQuery("SELECT SUM(mdcp.tot_potential * mp.mrp) as tot,SUM(mdcp.nrx * mp.mrp + mdcp.rrx * mp.mrp )/30 as Comptot,SUM((mdcp.nrx_qty - mdcp.nrx) * mp.mrp + (mdcp.rrx_qty - mdcp.rrx) * mp.mrp ) as Cmptot FROM master_doctor_cmpny_prod mdcp,master_product mp WHERE mdcp.doctor_id='$docId' AND mp.product_id=mdcp.product_id");
        $fetRx =$dbHandle->fetchObjectQuery($slRx);
        echo getCurrency().' '.$fetRx->tot .'/ month';
        ?>
      </font></li>

      <li><font size="2px"> Support for CHTND : <?php echo getCurrency().' '.round($fetRx->Comptot,2);?> </font></li>

      <li><font size="2px"> Competitior Support : <?php echo getCurrency().' '.$fetRx->Cmptot;?> </font></li>

      <li><font size="2px"> Last Visited : <?php
      $toDy = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $lvq = $dbHandle->execQuery("select DATEDIFF('$toDy',saved_on) as dt from  doctor_dcr where doctor_id='$docId'");
        $lvf = $dbHandle->fetchObjectQuery($lvq);
        if($lvf->dt != '')
        {
            if($lvf->dt > 0)
            {
                echo $lvf->dt.' Days ago';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'NA';
        }
        ?>
      </font></li>

      <li><font size="2px">Last 30 Days Ave Calls : <?php
        $tDate=date("Y-m-d");
        $toDate =strtotime ('-30 day',strtotime($tDate));
        $toDate=date ('Y-m-j',$toDate);
        $sCalls =$dbHandle->execQuery("SELECT * FROM doctor_dcr WHERE added_by='$usrId' AND flag='0' AND date(saved_on) BETWEEN '$toDate' AND '$tDate'");
        $nmRows =$dbHandle->getNumRows($sCalls);
        echo round($nmRows/30,2);
        ?>
      </font></li>
      <li><font size="2px"> Doctor Class : <?php echo $fetDoc->doc_class;?> </font></li>

    </ul>

  </div>
  <div id="working" class="datatab" style="display:none">
    <ul data-role=listview data-inset=true data-theme=d >

    <li data-theme=e><font size="2px"> Working Info </font></li>
        <?php 
        $tnt=0;
            function workLocation($ref)
            {
                GLOBAL $dbHandle;
                GLOBAL $docId;
                $wlData="";
                $h=0;
                if($ref == 'hospital')
                {
                    $slocDetails=$dbHandle->execQuery("SELECT hospital_id,hospital_name FROM doctor_hospital_link WHERE doctor_id='$docId'");
                    $getNR=$dbHandle->getNumRows($slocDetails);
                    if($getNR > 0)
                    {
                        while($fetDetails=$dbHandle->fetchObjectQuery($slocDetails))
                        {
                        $h++;
                            if($h < $getNR)
                            {
                                $wlData .='<a href="'.ROOT_PATH.'hospitalView.php?hospId='.$fetDetails->hospital_id.'">'.ucfirst($fetDetails->hospital_name).'</a>'.',';
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $wlData .='<a href="'.ROOT_PATH.'hospitalView.php?hospId='.$fetDetails->hospital_id.'">'.ucfirst($fetDetails->hospital_name).'</a>';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $wlData="NA";
                    }
                }
                else if($ref == 'clinic')
                {
                    $slocDetails=$dbHandle->execQuery("SELECT clinic_id,clinic_name FROM doctor_clinic_link WHERE doctor_id='$docId'");
                    $getNR=$dbHandle->getNumRows($slocDetails);
                    if($getNR > 0)
                    {
                        while($fetDetails=$dbHandle->fetchObjectQuery($slocDetails))
                        {
                        $h++;
                            if($h < $getNR)
                            {
                                $wlData .='<a href="'.ROOT_PATH.'clinicView.php?clinicId='.$fetDetails->clinic_id.'">'.ucfirst($fetDetails->clinic_name).'</a>'.',';
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $wlData .='<a href="'.ROOT_PATH.'clinicView.php?clinicId='.$fetDetails->clinic_id.'">'.ucfirst($fetDetails->clinic_name).'</a>';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $wlData="NA";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $slocDetails=$dbHandle->execQuery("SELECT chemist_id,chemist_name FROM doctor_chemist_link WHERE doctor_id='$docId'");
                    $getNR=$dbHandle->getNumRows($slocDetails);
                    if($getNR > 0)
                    {
                        while($fetDetails=$dbHandle->fetchObjectQuery($slocDetails))
                        {
                        $h++;
                            if($h < $getNR)
                            {
                                $wlData .='<a href="'.ROOT_PATH.'chemistView.php?chemistId='.$fetDetails->chemist_id.'">'.ucfirst($fetDetails->chemist_name).'</a>'.',';
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $wlData .='<a href="'.ROOT_PATH.'chemistView.php?chemistId='.$fetDetails->chemist_id.'">'.ucfirst($fetDetails->chemist_name).'</a>';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $wlData="NA";
                    }
                }
                return $wlData;
            }
        if(workLocation('hospital') != 'NA')
        {
        ?>
      <li><font size="2px"> Hospital Name : <?php echo workLocation('hospital');?></font></li>
      <?php
        }
        else
        {
            $tnt++;
        }
        if(workLocation('clinic'))
        {
        ?>
      <li><font size="2px"> Clinic Name :  <?php echo workLocation('clinic');?></font></li>
      <?php
        }
        else
        {
            $tnt++;
        }
        if(workLocation('chemist'))
        {
        ?>
        <li><font size="2px"> Chemist Name :  <?php echo workLocation('chemist');?></font></li>
      <?php
        }
        else
        {
            $tnt++;
        }
        if($tnt == 3)
        {
        ?>
        <li><font size="2px"> NO Data To Display</font></li>
        <?php
        }
        ?>      
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In `"header.php"` all js and css are there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
  Before You are calling to this page You have to specify in href like the following
```

assume that you are having the following link to load:

```
<a href="sample.php" rel="external">sample</a>
```

here `href="external"` You have to specify otherwise it wont work.....